# Maximum / Minimum Question with 3 Variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-programming

I seem to be stuck in this problem, would need your help!

Question: Assume I have :

147 of x,
                          174 of y,
                          238 of z

A different amount of x, y and z are being used to produce 3 different products A, B and C, satisfying the 3 equations below.

A = 10x + 5y + 3z,
B = 3x + 10y + 5z,
C = 5x + 3y + 10z

The question is how do I find out which combination of A, B and C I should produce in order to maximize the usage of the current resources and produce the maximum amount of A, B and C combined. (A + B + C will be maximum.) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do $x$, $y$ and $z$ have the same value?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code not necessarily, in fact, most likely not.  Any ideal solution will use as much of each as is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 2:

I initially thought it was a simple problem and now after you have given a counterexample, I created a LPP and solved in SOLVER EXCEL.  This is the perfect solution.  **Ignore my previous edit.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey there Satish, thank you for the help! 

But is there any mathematical reason why this works?

Oh and when I have tried this method, it seems like it can't work for all values - an example of the matrix B can be (1636, 713, 1092).

When B is multiplied by A-inverse, the result I got was (129.235, -16.9957, 78.92735)

Is there any method to solve this as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Derp, I created an LPP and solved for both the cases.  I have also given the setup in EXCEL.  Hopefully this answers your question thoroughly.  Ignore my previous method and I kind of thought it was simple and did linear system of equation and when you gave a counterexample , I develped this full fledged LPP.  Thanks